# Proof of the Strong Markov Property for Continuous Time Markov Chains

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 6.5.4 (the strong Markov
property for continuous time Markov chains) in J.R. Norris' book *Markov Chains*. It states that for $ X = (X_t)_{t
\geq 0}   $ Markov$ (λ,Q)  $ and $ T $ a stopping time of $ X $,
conditional on $ T < \zeta $ and $ X_T = i $, $
(X_{T+t})_{t  \geq 0}   $ is Markov$ (δ_i, Q)  $ and independent of $
\mathcal{F}_T $. Here, $ \zeta $ denotes the first explosion time of
the chain.

For completeness, the **proof** goes as follows: On $ \{ T < \zeta\} $ set $ \widetilde{X}_t =
X_{T+t} $ and denote $ (\widetilde{Y}_n)_{n  \geq 0}   $ the jump chain
and $ (\widetilde{S}_n)_{n  \geq 1}   $ the holding times of $
\widetilde{X} $. We want to show that for all $ A ∈ \mathcal{F}_T $, all
$ i_0,\ldots, i_n ∈ I $ and all $s_1,\ldots, s_n  \geq 0  $ it holds
that
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        &\mathbb{P}[ \{ \widetilde{Y}_0 = i_0, \ldots, \widetilde{Y}_n = i_n, 
            \widetilde{S}_1 > s_1,\ldots, \widetilde{S}_n > s_n\}  
            \cap A \cap \{ T < \zeta \} \cap \{ X_T =i\}  ] \\
        &= \mathbb{P}_i[ \{ Y_0 = i_0, \ldots, Y_{n}  = i_n, S_{1}  >
                s_1,\ldots, S_{n}  > s_n\}] \\
        &\quad \quad  \times \mathbb{P}[ A \cap  \{T < \zeta\} \cap \{ X_T
        =i\}  ]. \\            
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
It suffices to prove this with $ \{ T < \zeta\} $  replaced by $ \{ J_m
\leq T < J_{m+1} \} $ for $ m ∈ \mathbb{N}_0 $ arbitrary. In two lemmas
preceding the proof, it has been shown that

- $ \{ J_m  \leq T\} \cap \{X_T = i\} ∈ \mathcal{F}_T $, such that. w.l.o.g. $ A ⊆  \{ J_m  \leq T\}\cap \{X_T =i\}$ and
- Let $ \mathcal{G}_m = σ(Y_0,\ldots, Y_m, S_1,\ldots, S_m) $. Then there
  exist $ T_m $  and $ A_m $ which are $ \mathcal{G}_m$-measurable such
  that $ T = T_m $ and $ 1_{A} = 1_{A_m}   $ on $ \{ T < J_{m+1} \}  $

Conditional on $ Y_m = i $, $ S_{m+1}  $ is independent of $
\mathcal{G}_m $ and thus of $ T_m - J_m  $ and $ A_m $, so by
memorylessness of the exponential distribution
$$ \mathbb{P}][S_{m+1} > s_1 + (T_m - J_m) | Y_m = i, S_{m+1} > T_m  - J_m  ] =
e^{-q_i s_1} = \mathbb{P}_i[S_1 > s_1]  . $$
Hence by the Markov property of the jump chain
\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
        &\mathbb{P}[ \{ \widetilde{Y}_0 = i_0, \ldots, \widetilde{Y}_n = i_n, \\
            & \quad \ \ \widetilde{S}_1 > s_1,\ldots, \widetilde{S}_n > s_n\} \cap A \cap
            \{J_m  \leq T < J_{m+1}\} \cap \{ X_T =i\}  ] \\
        &= \mathbb{P}[ \{ Y_m = i_0, \ldots, Y_{m+n}  = i_n, S_{m+1} >
            s_1 + (T_m - J_m), \\ 
            & \quad \ \ S_{m+2}  > s_2,\ldots, S_{m+n}  > s_n\} \cap A_m \cap
            \{S_{m+1} > T_m - J_m \} ] \\
        &= \mathbb{P}_i[ \{ Y_0 = i_0, \ldots, Y_{n}  = i_n, \\
        & \quad \ \ S_{1}  > s_1,\ldots, S_{n}  > s_n\}] \mathbb{P}[ A \cap  
            \{J_m  \leq T < J_{m+1} \} \cap \{ X_T =i\}  ] \\            
    \end{aligned}
    \tag{$*$} 
\end{equation}

Now to the actual **question**: My problem lies in understanding the last set of manipulations,
specifically relating to the second bullet above. As I understand it, what is used (this would be Lemma 6.5.3. in the book) is that there exists a random variable $ T_m $, measurable w.r.t. $ \mathcal{G}_m $, with $ T_m 1_{\{ T < J_{m+1}\}} = T 1_{\{ T < J_{m+1}\}}  $. Clearly this implies $ \{T < J_{m+1} \} \subseteq  \{ T_m < J_{m+1}\}   $, but I don't see how it implies $ \{T <
J_{m+1} \} = \{T_m < J_{m+1} \} $, without which it is hard to make sense of the equalities in $ (*) $. Similarly with the switch from $ A $ to $ A_m $ - it seems to me as if the information $ T < J_{m+1}  $ was lost in the intermediate step.